# Assigning a number to a user when filling out an html questionnare

Tags: python, html, forms, csv, flask

I am creating a questionnare web application with html and python using flask. Currently, the html form inputs are saved to a CSV file, and the questionnare results are calculated with python code, by reading the csv file.

When the users answers are being saved to the CSV, I want to assign a "user response id" that indicates the response of a SPECIFIC user, so that when the questionnare results are calculated, they're calculated for this particular user. I am not sure how to do this. How do I assign an ID value for a user, for all their answers?

Here is how the responses to the questionnare are saved:

```
ID,Response_ID,Question_ID,Ans
1,2,1,1985
2,2,2,6
3,2,3,3000
4,2,4,2
```

So these would be the responses from user "2".
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable and increase it every time your function to save gets invoked.

```
counter = 1

def my_saving_function():
   #do something to add the counter variable into the data to be written to the CSV.
   counter++
```

If you're going to implement something like an SQL database to your app, you can just create an autoincrement integer column, then query it with something like MAX(ID_COLUMN) and add that to the CSV you're about to write.